# Update MailChimp List with PHP

Tags: php, mailchimp

I have a registration form on my site that submits a users registration information to a MySQL database via PHP. I would now like to also submit some of this information to a MailChimp list that I have created.

I do not want to use Mailchimp as the registration form, and I do not want mailchimp to send them an email to confirm their subscription (my current registration form already does that).

I know I can export my registrants to a cvs file then upload that directly, but I just want the users info to be automatically submitted. I have looked at the list subscribe thing but it appears that it will not do what I am looking for. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The [MailChimp API](http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/) provides methods for both being able to sign-up users and sync subscription information between MailChimp and your own system. (You'll need to do this to ensure your local state information is correct if you're allowing people to un-subscribe via the mailers that are transmitted.)

In terms of specific methods - see the various [list related methods](http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/rtfm/index.php#listrelated) which include facilities to [subscribe](http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/rtfm/listsubscribe.func.php) and [un-subscribe](http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/rtfm/listunsubscribe.func.php) users. (There are also bulk equivalents to these if you're batching such activity on your site.)

As you're using PHP, there's also a [PHP Wrapper](http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/downloads/#php) which will handle the underlying communications for you.